# How to parameterize ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add

Tags: excel, vba

please help with the below issue that I am facing in VBA

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add ' returns error when replacing URL with a variable having the same URL
```

Actual working code with a fixed URL:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="projects", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://.............."", [Headers=[Authorization=""Bearer ########-####-####-...........""]]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converted to Table"", ""Colu" & _
        "mn1"", {""id"", ""name""}, {""Column1.id"", ""Column1.name""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"""



    Dim pURL As String
    pURL = "https://........................"

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="projects", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(“”” & pURL& “””), [Headers=[Authorization=""Bearer ########-####-####-...........""]]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converted to Table"", ""Colu" & _
        "mn1"", {""id"", ""name""}, {""Column1.id"", ""Column1.name""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"""
```

I would like to replace the Source and Header fields in VBA with parameters but not working :(, can someone please on the above query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the url, the problem is that the name hasn't changed.
Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="projects2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(“”” & pURL& “””), [Headers=[Authorization=""Bearer ########-####-####-...........""]]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converted to Table"", ""Colu" & _
        "mn1"", {""id"", ""name""}, {""Column1.id"", ""Column1.name""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"""
```

Esentially you add a connection (which you can view under Data->Connections) but this each conncetion needs a unique name, you are not allowed to add a connection with an existing name. Also please be carful to delete the connections after you don't need them anymore, otherwise your worksheet will become really really slow, depending on the amount of connections.